# TSQL Update stmt for each column name according to data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

For SSIS, I need to create a TSQL update workflow to overwrite the current table records in case of an import error.

I already have a set up for the whole SSIS process but I'm missing the SQL update statement.

So if something goes wrong during the import the current records (all rows) in the table should be updated with a short message - "Error DB Import" for example.

Since I have multiple tables to deal with I also get **different column names and data types**.
I would use this stmt to get the column names

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME , * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'
```

but how can I set a string message for the char types and NULL for numeric and date types. Using a CASE stmt?

In pseudo-code it's probably just a loop through the columns: if column_name is of data_type "char" then...

I also need to **ignore the first 4 columns of each table** so that I don't overwrite ID, Date, etc.

If you can help me set up a static test update stmt I'm sure I will be able to transfer this to my SSIS project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE DATA_TYPE
    WHEN 'int' THEN NULL
    WHEN 'varchar' THEN 'STRING MSG GOES HERE'
  END,
COLUMN_NAME , * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'
  AND ORDINAL_POSITION > 4
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a44d/4)

You can add as many `WHEN` clauses to the `CASE` statement as needed.  Also, you want to use the `ORDINAL_POSITION` column to exclude the first 4 columns.

If you need to use this information to create an `UPDATE` statement, then you'll need to do that with Dynamic SQL.

*EDIT -- Dynamic SQL:*

```
create procedure updateMyTable
as 
begin
  declare @sql varchar(max)

  SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE myTable SET ' + 
  STUFF(
    (SELECT ', ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ' +
    CASE DATA_TYPE
      WHEN 'int' THEN 'NULL'
      WHEN 'varchar' THEN '''STRING MSG GOES HERE'''
    END 

   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'
   for xml path(''))
   ,1,1,'')

  exec(@sql)
end
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/568b5/1)

Comment: Thanks for the script. But I don't get how would I update the records in myTable with the string msg above?

Comment: thanks for the update and the fiddle. Now all I need to know is where to put my WHERE clause to only update a given ID. 
I added the ID to the fiddle [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d6d9/1/1)

Comment: I should add that I figured it out.